# Adding layer using QgsMapLayerRegistry within thread PyQGIS Plugin

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, plugins

I am developing Python QGIS plugin, where I am opening two threads in **run** function with one thread performing calculation while second thread is printing value **looping** and when first thread is completed i.e. when `self.letsGo` variable value changes to `True`, second thread should add the layer to the QGIS. Everything else is working perfectly fine i.e. it is printing the values in the log panel of QGIS, but when `self.letsGo` is changed to `True`, second thread detects it but does not add the layer to map. Is there any dependency of **QgsMapLayerRegistry** from threading and how can I fix it?

```py
def addLayertoMap(self):
    #add an empty layer to map
    vectorLayer = QgsVectorLayer('Polygon?crs=epsg:3857', 'testLayer' , 'memory')

    while (True):
        QgsMessageLog.logMessage("Looping")
        if self.letsGo==True:
            QgsMessageLog.logMessage("Detected")

            # QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vectorLayer)

            QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vectorLayer)

            QgsMessageLog.logMessage(str(lyr2.name()))
            for lyr in self.iface.mapCanvas().layers():
                QgsMessageLog.logMessage(lyr.name())
            QgsMessageLog.logMessage("Removed")

            break;
        time.sleep(0.5);    

def ouput(self):
    time.sleep(2)
    #connect to database and fetch results
    self.letsGo=True;

def run(self):
    t = threading.Thread(target=self.output)
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=self.addLayerToMap)
    t.start()
    t2.start()
```

**UPDATE**

I just figured out that **QgsMapLayerRegistry**  is adding layer to Project properties Identify Layer but not adding it to Layers Panel.

Answer (score 1):

How can this be implemented in QGIS3 API as the above is for the QGIS2 and QGIS3 API does not have QgsMapLayerRegistry?

Comment: "QgsMapLayerRegistry. Its functionality has been moved to QgsProject." (e.g https://qgis.org/api/api_break.html) so `QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer` in QGIS 2 is now `QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer` in QGIS 3